# Joomla This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below

Tags: ajax, xml, joomla, kunena

I have installed a component for joomla called MijoPolls, it work as is should until you vote with AJAX turned on. Then I get the above error when voting, but the weird thing is that when browsing Kunena forum, I can make a vote and it works flawless. What is different when browsing other sections of a joomla site vs browsing the kunena forum?

Also when browsing the kunena forum I have this error: Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/xxxxx/domains/xxxx.xx/public_html/components/com_content/router.php on line 69

I just hide it on my live site, but maybe it has something to do with the MijoPolls actually working when this error appear? I use a clean joomla and kunena install with no core files modified, would be glad if someone knew something about the notice too.

Comment: Kunena has great forums and also you might want to ask for help at the MijoPolls ste or on joomla.stackexchange.com [joomla.se].

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a style in the Mijo module in **"Module Class Suffix"** section of the module. Kunena has his own template and uses other style definitions. You could use a style definition from Kunena in the Mijo module.